# Pixels regions comparision

Tags: gimp, python-fu

I'm trying to write a python script for GIMP, who's aim is to slice a picture into a tileset (identify each unique 16x16 tiles in a picture).

So far, I'm able to read tiles (in fact a 16x16 pixels region) and write it somewhere.
But all my attempts at comparing tiles failed.

Did I miss Something ?
My script is as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gimpfu import *

    # compare 2 tiles,
    # return 1 if identical, false otherwise
def tileCompare(tile1, tile2):
    if(tile1 == tile2):
        return 1
    return 0

     # return tile at (x, y) coordinates
def readTile(layer, x, y):
    pr = layer.get_pixel_rgn(x,y,16,16)
    return pr[x:x+16, y:y+16]

    # write tile at (x, y) coordinates on given layer
def writeTile(layer, x, y, tile):    
    pr = layer.get_pixel_rgn(x,y,16,16)
    pr[x:x+16, y:y+16] = tile

def TilesSlicer(sourceLayer, targetLayer):
        # Actual plug-in code will go here

        # iterate tiles (result in tileSource)
    for x in range(0, sourceLayer.width, 16):
        for y in range(0, sourceLayer.height, 16):
            tileSource = readTile(sourceLayer, x, y)
            found = 0
                # iterate tiles again (result in tileIterator)
            for a in range(0, sourceLayer.width, 16):
                for b in range(0, sourceLayer.height, 16):
                    tileIterator = readTile(sourceLayer, x, y)
                        # compare tiles
                        # if identical and not yet found
                        # write it in the target layer
                    if (tileCompare(tileSource, tileIterator) == 1):
                        if(found == 0):
                            writeTile(tileIterator, a, b, tileSource)
                        found = 1

register(
    "TilesSlicer",
    "Tiles slicer",
    "Slice a picture into tiles",
    "Fabrice Lambert",
    "Fabrice Lambert",
    "April 2019",
    "Tiles slicer...",
    "RGB*",
    [
    (PF_DRAWABLE, "sourceLayer", "Source Layer: ", None),
    (PF_DRAWABLE, "targetLayer", "Target Layer: ", None),
    ],
    [],
    TilesSlicer,
        menu="<Image>/Filters/My Scripts")

main()
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Please elaborate "my attempts failed". How can you tell they failed? Did you get an error? If so, please add it.

Comment: Reading a tile at the same coordinates (in other words: the same tile), and comparing return 0 (while it should return 1), see the tileCompare function..

Comment: Typically the first argument of your plugin should be an image. If the the first two args are an image and a "drawable", then they are assumed to be the active image and drawable (layer, mask or channel), and the auto-generated parameter dialog will only ask for the additional arguments, the target layer in your case. But the Gimp convention is that the active layer is the modified one, so you should have Image/Target/Source. If you play with tiles in Python you can use Numpy, see [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Gimp-python-and-numpy).

Comment: 1st: It depend what you expect it to do:
Slice the whole image ?
Slice one layer ?
I picked the 2nd option, since one can have "work layers" not supposed to be sliced.

2nd: Arguments are not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm,

I found the problem:
tileIterator = readTile(sourceLayer, a, b)
instead of:
tileIterator = readTile(sourceLayer, x, y)

Answer (score 0):

Alright,

After refining a bit, the script is as follow:
- Added tiles width and height to handle any tile size.
- Removed target layer parameter, the script now create it.
- Added real time display to give feedbacks to the user (sadly, progress bar doesn't work).
- Improved speed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gimpfu import *

    # compare 2 tiles,
    # return 1 if identical, 0 otherwise
def tileCompare(tile1, tile2):
    if(tile1 == tile2):
        return 1
    return 0

     # return tile at (x, y) coordinates
def readTile(layer, x, y, width, height):
    pr = layer.get_pixel_rgn(x, y, width, height)
    return pr[x:x+width, y:y+height]

    # write tile at (x, y) coordinates on given layer
def writeTile(layer, x, y, width, height, tile):    
    pr = layer.get_pixel_rgn(x, y, width, height)
    pr[x:x+width, y:y+height] = tile
    layer.update(x, y, width, height)
    gimp.displays_flush()

def TilesSlicer(sourceLayer, tileWidth, tileHeight):
        # Actual plug-in code will go here
    if((sourceLayer.width % tileWidth) != 0):
        gimp.message("The layer width is not multiple of " + str(tileWidth))
        gimp.quit()
    if((sourceLayer.height % tileWidth) != 0):
        gimp.message("The layer height is not multiple of " + str(tileHeight))
        gimp.quit()
    totalTiles = (sourceLayer.width / tileWidth) * (sourceLayer.height / tileHeight)
    tilesProcessed = 0

    gimp.progress_init("Processing...")
    gimp.progress_update(0.0)

    sourceImage = sourceLayer.image
    targetLayer = pdb.gimp_layer_new(sourceImage, sourceLayer.width, sourceLayer.height, sourceImage.base_type, "Target", 100.0, sourceLayer.mode)
    targetLayer.add_alpha()
    targetLayer.fill(TRANSPARENT_FILL)
    sourceImage.add_layer(targetLayer, 0)
        # iterate tiles (result in tileSource)
    for x in range(0, sourceLayer.width, tileWidth):
        for y in range(0, sourceLayer.height, tileHeight):
            tileSource = readTile(sourceLayer, x, y, tileWidth, tileHeight)
            found = 0
                # iterate tiles again (result in tileIterator)
            for a in range(0, sourceLayer.width, tileWidth):
                for b in range(0, sourceLayer.height, tileHeight):
                    tileIterator = readTile(sourceLayer, a, b, tileWidth, tileHeight)
                        # compare tiles
                        # if identical and not yet found
                        # write it in the target layer
                        # and abort iteration (for speed purpose)
                    if (tileCompare(tileSource, tileIterator) == 1):
                        if(found == 0):
                            writeTile(targetLayer, a, b, tileWidth, tileHeight, tileIterator)
                        found = 1
                        break
                if(found == 1):
                    break
            tilesProcessed = tilesProcessed + 1
            gimp.progress_update(tilesProcessed / totalTiles)
            gimp.displays_flush()

register(
    "TilesSlicer",
    "Tiles slicer",
    "Slice a picture into tiles",
    "Fabrice Lambert",
    "Fabrice Lambert",
    "April 2019",
    "Tiles slicer...",
    "RGB*",
    [
    (PF_DRAWABLE, "sourceLayer", "Source Layer: ", None),
    (PF_INT8, "tileWidth", "Tile width: ", 16),
    (PF_INT8, "tileHeight", "Tile height: ", 16),
    ],
    [],
    TilesSlicer, 
        menu="<Image>/Filters/My Scripts")

main()
```

It can probably be refined better, and if someone have anything to deal with the progress bar, let me know.
I'm open to suggestions.